# Pgadmin sql malformed array literal - No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. Got this error when I execute below query in pg.

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT("c"."id")) AS "cnt" FROM "company" "c" 
LEFT JOIN "company_participants" "p" ON "p"."company_id"="c"."id"  
LEFT JOIN "company_step" "cs" ON "cs"."id"="c"."current_step_id"  
LEFT JOIN "brand" "brand" ON "brand"."id"="c"."brand_id"  
LEFT JOIN "user" "projectLead" ON "projectLead"."id"="c"."project_lead_id" 
WHERE "p"."user_id" = 126 AND "c"."project_type" IN (1,2)
```

**Query Builder:**

```
qb = this.createQueryBuilder('c')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('c.participants', 'p')
        .where('p.userId = :id', { id: requestOwner.id })
        .select(['c', 'cs.name', 'cs.id', 'user', 'c.createdBy'])
        .leftJoin('c.currentStep', 'cs')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('c.brand', 'brand')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('c.projectLead', 'projectLead');
```

**Entity class:**

```
  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: ProjectTypeEnum,
    array: true,
    nullable: true,
  })
  projectType: ProjectTypeEnum[];
```

Below snippet is for adding filter and pagination on Project type column -
How do we provide schema option in nest.js for data type in postgresql for projecttype is as below =>
datatype: **campaign_project_type_enum[]** and
default value: **'{4}':: campaign_project_type_enum[]**

```
const arraySchemaOptions = {
    type: 'array',
    items: {
      type: 'string'
    },
  };
```

Comment: How is the `projectType` column related to the failing query? It doesn't appear to be used anywhere.

Comment: The issue likely arises from the WHERE "p"."user_id" = 126 condition or the "c"."project_type" IN (1,2) condition.

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com, both of those are correct: `select 1 in (1,2); t` and `select 126 = 126; t`.  The issue is with something Postgres thinks is an array but is not properly formatted as one.

Comment: I would say this down to how ever `campaign_project_type_enum[] ` is defined and where it is actually used? You need to add that information to your question text.